# Convert a date in string YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD in JSTL

Tags: date, jstl

I have a string field that is shown as a date in YYYY-MM-DD format.  I am trying to convert this field on my JSP to MM/DD date format. Here is the JSTL code I have now:

```
        <fmt:parseDate var="taxFromDate" value="${a8spt214.fromDate}" pattern="MM-dd"/>   
        <fmt:parseDate var="taxToDate" value="${a8spt214.toDate}" pattern="MM-dd"/>
```

When I try running this I get a compile error saying the following

```
 In &lt;parseDate&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed: "2017-06-30"] with root cause java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-06-30"
```

is it possible to convert a string to a date filed in JSP without actually using the year in the format?  Or is the pattern invalid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code to show this type of date `MM/DD/YY`

```
<p>Formatted Date : <fmt:formatDate type = "both" 
         dateStyle = "short" timeStyle = "short" value = "${now}" /></p>
```

The Code above will Print this result:

```
Formatted Date : 23/09/10 14:27
```

I hope to help you solve problem.

Comment: Is it possible to show a date format without the year?  Like in your example I would rather see 23/09.  Thanks for the response

Comment: No because `type="both"` or `Date` print MM/DD/YY